# Regex JSON String Mask

Tags: java, regex

I am using the following code to mask first 5 chars of JSON Value and it works as expected.

```java
String s = "{ \"Name1\":\"Cristhoper David\", \"pass\":\"123456789123\" }";

System.out.println(s
        .replaceAll("(?<=Name1\":\")(.{1,5})(.*?)", "*****$2")
        .replaceAll("(?<=pass\":\")(.{1,5})(.*?)", "*****$2")
);
```

Output:

```
{ "Name1":"*****hoper David", "pass":"*****6789123" }
```

But when the Name1 is less than 5 chars the JSON is getting improper and `"` and `,` signs are getting disappeared as in following example:

```java
String s = "{ \"Name1\":\"Joe\", \"pass\":\"123456789123\" }";

System.out.println(s
        .replaceAll("(?<=Name1\":\")(.{1,5})(.*?)", "*****$2")
        .replaceAll("(?<=pass\":\")(.{1,5})(.*?)", "*****$2")
);
```

Output:

```
{ "Name1":"***** "pass":"*****6789123" }
```

Here `"` and `,` got removed.

And for the following as well

```java
String s = "{ \"Name1\":\"Jo\", \"pass\":\"123456789123\" }";

System.out.println(s
        .replaceAll("(?<=Name1\":\")(.{1,5})(.*?)", "*****$2")
        .replaceAll("(?<=pass\":\")(.{1,5})(.*?)", "*****$2")
);
```

Output:

```
{ "Name1":"*****"pass":"*****6789123" }
```

If `Name1` is less than 5 chars I want it to be

```
{ "Name1":"*****","pass":"*****6789123" }
```

How should I correct my regex to handle this?

Comment: Maybe have a go with [`(\"(?:Name1|pass)\":\")[^\"]{1,5}`](https://regex101.com/r/Oei11h/1)

Comment: Change `.{1,5}` to `[^"]{1,5}` so you only change 5 characters or until you find `"` which is the delimiter for JSON entries

Comment: Hi @JvdV ,Thanks for the reply,What will be the regex to do the same thing for xml?Example:<Name1>john guten berg</Name1> -- ><Name1>*****guten berg</Name1>

Comment: @JabbarKhan, do you mean [`(<(?:Name1|pass)>)[^<]{1,5}`](https://regex101.com/r/9296Lu/1) maybe ?

Comment: Thanks @JvdV,It works!!,Is there a way to Print stars of string count if it is less than 5 Chars?For example :<Name1>Joe</Name1> -- ><Name1>***</Name1>,Need to handle in one line same regex..

Comment: You have a lot of follow-up questions @JabbarKhan which is starting to deviate from your OP quite a bit and seems to look like an [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I answered below, hoping I covered what it is you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Initial question:*

Mask first 5 characters of value and if value is less than 5 characters, still replace with a constant of 5 characters. OP wanted this done for [Json](https://regex101.com/r/Oei11h/1) and [XML](https://regex101.com/r/9296Lu/1) in a later stage.

---

*Actual question:*

It became clear through the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76051735/regex-json-string-mask/76052707#comment134129056_76051735) that OP is actually looking to replace up to the first 5 characters of a value within XML-string. Therefor try:

```
(?<=<(?:Name1|pass)>[^<]{0,4})[^<]
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/h6zWrt/1)

- `(?<=` - Open positive lookbehind;

  - `(?:Name1|pass)` - Non-capture group to match either 'Name1' or 'pass' literally;
  - `>[^<]{0,4})` - Match a literal '>' and 0-4 characters other than '<' before we close the lookbehind;
- `[^<]` - Match a single character other than '<'.

The same technique could be applied for a Json-string:

```
(?<=\"(?:Name1|pass)\":\"[^\"]{0,4})[^\"]
```

Or, a little less strict, but probably good enough for now, a mix of both options:

```
(?<=[<\"](?:Name1|pass)(?:>|\":\")[^<\"]{0,4})[^<\"]
```

Comment: Thanks For the reply @JvdV,The answer works for Xml,Actually need to replace in JSON as well,What would be the changed regex for (?<=<(?:Name1|pass)>[^<]{0,4})[^<] to work for JSON? For Example :"Name1":"Joe" -- >"Name1":"***"

Comment: @JabbarKhan, so use the same principle: [`(?<=\"(?:Name1|pass)\":\"[^\"]{0,4})[^\"]`](https://regex101.com/r/cypES0/1), or,  a little less strict, all in a single expression like [`(?<=[<\"](?:Name1|pass)(?:>|\":\")[^<\"]{0,4})[^<\"]`](https://regex101.com/r/wC5PDT/1)

Comment: Hi @JvdV,How to i display only first 100 characters in  (?<=[<\"](?:Name1|pass)(?:>|\":\")[^<\"]{0,4})[^<\"] Regex?

Answer (score 0):

The added pattern `|(?<=Name1\":\)(.+?)"`matches the case where Name1 has fewer than 5 characters. The `.+?`means one or more characters.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this if you change your regex like this

`(?<=Name1\":\")([^"]{1,5})(.*?)`

- `.` matches any character
- `[^"]` matches all but `"`.
  So it will stop at the `"` after the name.
  The selected group (`$1`) then can have 1..5 characters.
  If `Name1` is `""`, then it will be `""` in the output too.

By the way: you have the same problem with "pass".

Your code shoud look like:

```java
System.out.println(s.
                   replaceAll("(?<=Name1\":\")([^\"]{1,5})(.*?)", "*****$2").
                   replaceAll("(?<=pass\":\")([^\"]{1,5})(.*?)",  "*****$2")
                  );
```

[Look at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/W8KizH/2)